# Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am getting this error while building my app (or running it).

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Interface `com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBuffer(classpath class)` used as super class of `com.google.android.gms.games.multiplayer.ParticipantBuffer`.

I have tried everything (from cleaning up project to invalidating caches and restarting android studio), but this error is not going anywhere and I have no idea what to do. So can help me find any solution for this error?

Here is my `app` level gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
lintOptions {
    disable 'ValidFragment'
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.littmedia.littapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.20170624"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.31.0'
implementation project(':firebase_plugin')
implementation project(':sdk')
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation project(':facebook')
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3'
implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.2'
implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.9'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'org.jdeferred:jdeferred-android-aar:1.2.4'
implementation('de.greenrobot:greendao:1.3.7@jar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2@jar'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my `project` level gradle file

```
buildscript {
repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance.